# How to sort values in a Multi-index while keeping the index structure

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'd like to sort data of a multi-index dataframe, while keeping higher level indexes the same.

Here is the data sample:

```py
data = {
    'Column 1': [1., 2., 3., 4.,34,2,5,6],
    'Index1 Title': [
        "Apples", "Apples", "Puppies", "Puppies",
        'Oranges','Oranges','Blue berries','Blue berries'],
    'index2 Title': [
        'Inside', 'Outside', 'Inside', 'Outside',
        'Inside', 'Outside', 'Inside', 'Outside'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['Index1 Title','index2 Title'],inplace=True)
```

I get this output:

```
Index1 Title index2 Title  Column 1
Apples       Inside         1.0
             Outside        2.0
Puppies      Inside         3.0
             Outside        4.0
Oranges      Inside         34.0
             Outside        2.0
Blue berries Inside         5.0
             Outside        6.0
```

When I try this bit of code:

`df.sort_values('Column 1', ascending=False)`

I get this:

```
Index1 Title    index2 Title    Column 1
Oranges         Inside          34.0
Blue berries    Outside         6.0
                Inside          5.0
Puppies         Outside         4.0
                Inside          3.0
Apples          Outside         2.0
Oranges         Outside         2.0
Apples          Inside          1.0
```

What I am trying to get, is something resembling what you would get using a pivot table on Excel, as so:

```
Index1 Title    index2 Title    Column 1
Oranges         Inside          34
                Outside         2
Blue berries    Inside          5
                Outside         6
Puppies         Inside          3
                Outside         4
Apples          Inside          1
                Outside         2
```

Basically making a sum of each **Index1 Title** values, and sorting them while keeping the **Index2 Title** structure intact.

I've been struggling with this for a certain time now, couldn't find a fix using standard `pandas` multi-indexing. Even the `reset_inde`x/`sort_index` routine didn't work

Would a for loop solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort_values` accepts index names, so you can do:

```
df.sort_values(['Index1 Title', 'Column 1'], ascending=[True, False])
```

output:

```
                           Column 1
Index1 Title index2 Title          
Apples       Outside            2.0
             Inside             1.0
Blue berries Outside            6.0
             Inside             5.0
Oranges      Inside            34.0
             Outside            2.0
Puppies      Outside            4.0
             Inside             3.0
```

---

**Update** Actually, I think I got what you want. There isn't a direct way to do this. You need to create a new series, sort that and reindex the data:

```
sorted_sum = (df.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
                .sort_values(['Column 1', 'index2 Title'], 
                              ascending=[False,True], 
                              kind='mergesort')
             )

df.loc[sorted_sum.index]
```

Output:

```
                           Column 1
Index1 Title index2 Title          
Oranges      Inside            34.0
             Outside            2.0
Blue berries Inside             5.0
             Outside            6.0
Puppies      Inside             3.0
             Outside            4.0
Apples       Inside             1.0
             Outside            2.0
```

**Note** can't understand why the 2nd level index is reversed, even with `mergesort`.

Comment: nice use of transform!

Comment: Excellent idea ! 
For the purposes of my work, this is perfect. The reversion is secondary. Probably a bug. 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @QuangHoang, made an edit to your code that returns the expected output. Kindly revert if you are not ok with it. As a dataframe, you can sort on the column and index at the same time

Comment: For my purpose it works okay. So I will keep @Quang Hoang's answer as accepted. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `.reindex` with the `level` argument to change 1 or more levels of a `MultiIndex` without changing the order of the others:

```
sorted_sums = df["Column 1"].sum(level=0).sort_values(ascending=False)
out = df.reindex(sorted_sums.index, level=0)

print(out)
                           Column 1
Index1 Title index2 Title
Oranges      Inside            34.0
             Outside            2.0
Blue berries Inside             5.0
             Outside            6.0
Puppies      Inside             3.0
             Outside            4.0
Apples       Inside             1.0
             Outside            2.0
```

Also- if memory serves me correctly there was a bug in the `level` argument of `reindex`. I did this on pandas version `1.1.1` so I can't guarantee it'll work on earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Elegant one at that !

Comment: I tip off my hat to you, what a brilliant solution. This deserves way more upvotes!